# I cannot create a project in Linux

Tags: linux, elixir

Two months taught Elixir in Windows. There was no problem. He created projects using the "mix new name_project" command. I decided to try Elixir on Linux. Linux Mint Cinnamon 19 Is Installed. Erlang and Elixir are installed and the Elixir software environment is running. And the project cannot be created. It seems, swears on syntax.
On the picture of the window you can see that the program shell starts, reacts to simple actions. And project create not is obtained. Is there a problem?
https://yapx.ru/v/FW5YF

Comment: I tried, it doesn't help. Why in Windows works and in Linux there is no? Maybe I configured Linux incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

You are using elixir 1.3.3, which does not support OTP 20, this seems like a likely cause for the issues.  I suggest upgrading elixir as 1.3 is pretty old and no longer getting fixes.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/pages/Compatibility%20and%20Deprecations.md

Comment: You were right, the problem is the old version. Put a new version and everything worked. All thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad, as @{Kalvin Hom} mentioned, you have quite old version of elixir that is not compatible with erlang OTP.

- remove elixir and OTP from your OS.
- install [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf-vm?id=install-asdf-vm) to manage elixir and erlang version
- add elixir-plugin and erlang-plugin:

```sh
$> asdf plugin-add erlang
$> asdf plugin-add elixir
```

- then install elixir and erlang via asdf

```sh
$> asdf install erlang 22.1.1
$> asdf install elixir 1.9.1
```

Now you have newest elixir and erlang on your machine. Take a look to asdf manual to know how to manage version via `.tool-versions` file